# Binary Search Tree implementation with unique pointers

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c++11, design-patterns, pointers

I have implemented a binary search tree using templates and unique_ptr in C++ 11. At present, only insertion and deletion are implemented. Please provide your feedback for improvements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


template<typename T>
class Btree {
public:
    void insert(T data)
    {
        _insert(root, data);
    }
    void traverse(void (*func)(T data))
    {
        _traverse(root, func);
    }
    void del(T data)
    {
        _del(root, data);
    }
private:
    struct node {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<node> left, right;
        node(T data): data(data), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    };

    std::unique_ptr<node> root;
    void _insert(std::unique_ptr<node>& curr, T data);
    void _del(std::unique_ptr<node>& curr, T data);
    void _traverse(std::unique_ptr<node>& curr, void (*func)(T data));
    T _findmin(std::unique_ptr<node> &curr);
};

template<typename T>
void Btree<T>::_insert(std::unique_ptr<node>& curr, T data)
{
    if (curr == nullptr) {
        curr.reset(new node(data));
        return;
    }

    if (data < curr->data)
        _insert(curr->left, data);
    else
        _insert(curr->right, data);
}
template<typename T>
T Btree<T>::_findmin(std::unique_ptr<node>& curr)
{
    if (curr && curr->left == nullptr)
        return curr->data;
    return _findmin(curr->left);    
}
template<typename T>
void Btree<T>::_del(std::unique_ptr<node>& curr, T data)
{
    if (curr == nullptr)
        return;
    if (data < curr->data)
        _del(curr->left, data);
    else if (data > curr->data)
        _del(curr->right, data);
    else {
        // if one child is nullptr or both child are nullptr
        if (curr->left == nullptr) {
            auto &p = curr->right;
            curr.reset(p.release());
        }
        else if (curr->right == nullptr) {
            auto &p = curr->left;
            curr.reset(p.release());
        }
        //if child is non leaf node    
        else {
            T temp = _findmin(curr->right);
            curr->data = temp;
            _del(curr->right, temp);
        }
    }
}
template<typename T>
void Btree<T>::_traverse(std::unique_ptr<node>& curr, void (*func)(T data))
{
    if (curr == nullptr)
        return;
    _traverse(curr->left, func);
    func(curr->data);
    _traverse(curr->right, func);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Observations

You pass data by value. This is fine for small data types like `int`. But imagine that `T` is some huge object that is very expensive to copy. You should think of passing the data by reference to avoid any intermediate copies. When you get a bit more advanced think about passing by r-value reference to allow you to move the objects.

For your traversal you pass a function pointer. This is a bit limiting. Normally you would templateze the function to allow you to pass any function like object (function pointer/functor/lambda/std::function) etc.

Yes you need recursion when traversing trees. But you don't need it everywhere. There are a couple of places where a simple loop would be sufficient.

I can see why you use `std::unique_ptr`. But in my view a tree is a container and should manage its own memory. So I would have simply used `Node*` inside data. The code is not that much harder to write in this context. **BUT** I don't have any real issue with `std::unique_ptr`.

#### Code

Insert by const reference

```
void insert(T const& data)
{
    _insert(root, data);
}
_insert(std::unique_ptr<node>& curr, T const& data)
{
    if (curr.get() == nullptr) {
        curr.reset(new node(data));
        return;
    }

    auto& next = (data < curr->data) ? curr->left : curr->right;
    _insert(next, data);
}
```

Insert by r-Value reference

```
void insert(T&& data)
{
    _insert(root, std::forward<T>(data));
}
_insert(std::unique_ptr<node>& curr, T&& data)
{
    if (curr.get() == nullptr) {
        curr.reset(new node(data));
        return;
    }

    auto& next = (data < curr->data) ? curr->left : curr->right;
    _insert(next, std::forward<T>(data));
}
```

Emplace into node.

```
// This calls T constructor only when you construct the node itself.
template<typename... Args>
void emplace(Args const&... args)
{
    _emplace(root, args...));
}
template<typename... Args>
_emplace(std::unique_ptr<node>& curr, Args const&... args)
{
    if (curr.get() == nullptr) {
        curr.reset(new node(args...));
        return;
    }

    auto& next = (data < curr->data) ? curr->left : curr->right;
    _insert(next, args...);
}
template<typename... Args>
node::node(Args const&... args)
    : data(args...)  // Data of type T constructed in place
    , left(nullptr)
    , right(nullptr)
{}
```

Using a function like object to traverse the tree:

```
template<typename F>
void traverse(const & action)
{
    _traverse(root, action);
}
template<typename F>
void _traverse(std::unique_ptr<node>& curr, F const& action);


// outside class

template<typename T>
template<typename F>
void Btree<T>::_traverse(std::unique_ptr<node>& curr, F const& action)
{
    if (curr == nullptr)
        return;
    _traverse(curr->left, action);
    action(curr->data);
    _traverse(curr->right, action);
}

int main()
{
     Btree<int>  tree;
     tree.traverse([](int x){std::cout << x << " ";});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your review comments. For traversal (passing any function like object), can you please show an example ?

Comment: @bornfree: OK modified traverse so you can pass a functor or a function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `insert` gets its data by value, you're making multiple copies of that data as you navigate down the tree to find where to add the new node.  Passing the parameter by `const T&` (so you only make one copy) would avoid these copies, a benefit for types that are expensive to copy.  Another possibility is to use `T &&` to move the data, but this will change the original value being passed in which may be undesirable.

The value passed to the function called by `_traverse` is also copied.  Depending on your needs, this could also use a `const T &`, or overloads of `_traverse` that take `func` with a reference could be provided.  The downside to providing access to the data via a reference is that it can allow that data to be altered.

If `_insert` takes `curr` as a pointer (`std::unique_ptr<node>* curr`) then you can use a loop rather than recursion.  This also applies to `_findmin` and `_del`.